# Saving URI image or converting to bitmap while maintaining resolution

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera, saving-data

So I've got my image to successfully pass to a URI...however I don't know how to save it or convert it to a bitmap while still maintaining resolution.  Any suggestions? Thank you.

```
photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // CALL THE PICTURE (this works)

            File t = new File (STORAGE_PATH + "savedAndroid.jpg");
            mURI = Uri.fromFile(t);
            i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            i.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mURI);
            startActivityForResult(i,0); //0 is default camera
        }
    });

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    imageView.setImageURI(mURI); //this seems to work...by itself


      //save the image or convert it to a bitmap to use with tesseract...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(mURI);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, new BitmapFactory.Options());
```

Then use it however you want.
Hope this helps.